# IDataErrorInfo issue when control is created as 'Collapsed'

Tags: wpf, datatrigger, idataerrorinfo

**EDIT** I'm adding additional code for clarification...

I am having an issue with getting the IDataErrorInfo error indicator to display on a control that initially is created "Collapsed", then is made visible with a DataTrigger.

There is a ComboBox control that binds to a lookup value, it displays three rows... "Cash", "Credit Card", and "Check".
I have two TextBox controls that bind to a "CreditCardCode" and a "CheckNumber" respectively.

The TextBox controls have a DataTrigger set to make them visible only if the related ComboBox value is selected.  The data error logic will show an error if the related TextBox has no value.

Here is the XAML for the combobox and textbox:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="False" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PaymentType}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource paymentTypeLookup}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding PaymentTypeCode}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PaymentTypeCode,
                                  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

<TextBox Name="CCCodeText" 
    Text="{Binding CreditCardCode, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
           ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PaymentComboBox, 
                                       Path=SelectedItem.PaymentTypeCode}" 
                             Value="CC_SWIPE">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" 
                                      Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Here is the code for the PaymentType object

```
public virtual PaymentType PaymentType
{
    get { return _paymentType; }
    set
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_paymentType, value))
        {
            var previousValue = _paymentType;
            _paymentType = value;
            FixupPaymentType(previousValue);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PaymentType");
            OnPaymentTypeChanged(value);
        }
    }
}
private PaymentType _paymentType;
```

Here is the OnPaymentTypeChanged() function:

```
void OnPaymentTypeChanged(PaymentType value)
{
    errors.Remove("CheckNumber"); //Avoid Dupes
    errors.Remove("CreditCardCode"); //Avoid Dupes

    if (this.PaymentType != null)
    {
        if (value.PaymentTypeCode == "CHECK" && 
           (this.CheckNumber == String.Empty || this.CheckNumber == null))
           errors.Add("CheckNumber", "Check Number required");

        else if (value.PaymentTypeCode == "CC_SWIPE" 
                 && (this.CreditCardCode == String.Empty || 
                     this.CreditCardCode == null))
            errors.Add("CreditCardCode", "Credit Card Code required");
    }
}
```

If the ComboBox is set to "Credit Card" when the window first displays (and the CCCodeText control is visible), the default red border displays fine.  But if I change the value of the ComboBox to "Check", and the CheckTextBox control appears, it's missing the red border.

When I change the ComboBox back to "Credit Card", the red border is still there.

Am I missing a refresh property somewhere???

Comment: I think more code is needed for us to get to helping you.

Comment: Thanks Rhyous, I've added the xaml for the combobox and the code that creates the IDataErrorInfo record.